# JasperReports html export

Tags: html, height, width, jasper-reports, render

I have developed a report in JasperReports, it appears fine when exported as PDF, but when I export same report as HTML it appears smaller in size. Does anyone have any idea, how is it possible to set the parameters so that it displays properly in PDF & HTML. Also is it possible to specify the pageWidth height etc. as percentages

Comment: How does it appear smaller? Are the font sizes smaller?

Comment: The font sizes are smaller also the images appear smaller. Is it possible to specify sizes in percentages, so that they appear properly in different screen resolutions

Comment: Maybe you should check out [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/project/ireport).

Comment: @Rakesh Are your sure that the browser settings (font size, etc.) do not affect? Jasper ultimate guide says: The unit of measurement used by iReport and
JasperReports is the pixel (which has a resolution of 75 dpi, or dots per inch).

Answer (score 1):

Look at the source of html, you may find the font unit is px, however PDF is using the font unit pt, that's why the html font is smaller than pdf. So you may need the following code to set the html font unit to pt.

```
 exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.SIZE_UNIT, JRHtmlExporterParameter.SIZE_UNIT_POINT);
```